# Inertia SSR + Vite + Laravel assets versioning issue

Tags: laravel, vite, assets, inertiajs

I'm new to Inertia and just playing with it. What I really don't understand why browser loads all assets on each redirect when using SSR. For redirect I'm using LINK component and also using layout (added image to layout to test it and it's loading on each redirect)

I followed Inertia docs and everything seems to be working.
Is it caused by assets versioning? Or...?

app.js

```
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue'
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'
import Layout from './layouts/Layout.vue'

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: async name => {
        const page = await resolvePageComponent(`./pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue'))
        page.default.layout ??= Layout
        return page
    },
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        createSSRApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mount(el)
    },
})
```

ssr.js

```
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import createServer from '@inertiajs/vue3/server'
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-renderer'
import { createSSRApp, h } from 'vue'
import Layout from './layouts/Layout.vue'
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers'

createServer(page =>
    createInertiaApp({
        page,
        render: renderToString,
        resolve: async name => {
            const page = await resolvePageComponent(`./pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./pages/**/*.vue'))
            page.default.layout ??= Layout
            return page
        },
        setup({ App, props, plugin }) {
            return createSSRApp({
                render: () => h(App, props),
            }).use(plugin)
        },
    }),
)
```

Layout.vue

```
<template>
    <main>
        <header>
            <Link href="/">Home</Link>
            <Link href="/about">About</Link>
            <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
        </header>
        <img src="../../img/test.png" alt="test" style="width: 400px" />
        <article>
            <slot />
        </article>
    </main>
</template>

<script setup>
import { Link } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Be careful what you install because instead of

@inertiajs/vue3

I installed

@inertiajs/inertia-vue3